# Will iText 7 render ChartJS chart?

Tags: javascript, html, itext, chart.js, itext7

Is it possible to render a [ChartJS](https://chartjs.com/) chart within a PDF generated by [iText 7](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7) (`iText.Html2Pdf.HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument`)? This is a dot net core project.

When I try to do this I get an empty space in the PDF where the chart is supposed to appear. Rest of the PDF renders correctly.

If I save the HTML to a file it does render the chart correctly in the browser.

I can share the code, but wanted to check first if `iText.Html2Pdf.HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument` will even attempt to render the chart or not.